# Does the iPhone offer a good Cryptographic API/Service Provider?

Tags: iphone, cryptography, pki

How extensive are the Cryptographic options offered by Apple for the iPhone OS? Does it have public key infrastructure support? Can the Keystore (or I guess keychain) be leveraged by third party applications and are they able to pull/store private keys there? What about support for the LDAP for pulling user's public certificates?

Answer (score 1):

[Mac OS X and iPhone OS Security Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/SecuritySvcs.html)

Comment: I have read that and was very dissapointed with how non-technical it was. Not to mention that it blows up my Internet Explorer.